# Injectivity of a complex function

Tags: functions

How come that $f(z)=z^3$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is not injective on an open set $U$ with the origin deleted?

Answer (score 5):

$re^{i2\pi/3}$ and $re^{i4\pi/3}$ go to the same place for any $r$ as small as you need it to be inside $U$.